# Distribution function of random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Given the distribution function of a random variable $X$, $F_X$, I would like to determine the distribution function of the random variable $Y = |X^2-1|$, that is, $Y = g(X)$ for $g(x)=|x^2-1|$. So
\begin{align*}
F_Y(y) &= \mathrm P\{Y \leq y\} = \mathrm P \{ |X^2-1| \leq y \} = \mathrm P \{ -y \leq X^2- 1 \leq y\}\\
&= \mathrm P\{-y+ 1 \leq X^2 \leq y + 1\} = \mathrm P\{\sqrt{1-y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{1+y}\}\\
\end{align*}
assumming that $y \geq 0$ clearly since $|X^2-1|\leq y$ or, equivalently, $g^{-1}(-\infty,y] = \emptyset$ for all $y < 0$. Hence $F_Y(y) = 0$ for $y < 0$ but I don't know how to justify that $y \leq 1$ (otherwise $\sqrt{1-y}\not\in\mathbb R$). Thanks in advance.

**Edit I** It is clear that the previous attempted justification is absurd, so I would do the following:
$$ \{ 1-y\leq X^2 \leq 1+y\} = \{1-y\leq X^2 < 0\} \sqcup \{0\leq X^2 \leq 1+y\} $$
where the first set in the union is $\emptyset$.
So I'll need to discuss that if $y > 1$:
$$ F_Y(y) = \mathrm P \{ 0\leq X \leq \sqrt{1+y}\}. $$
Is this right?

Comment: $\sqrt{X^2}=|X|$

Comment: You cannot justify that $Y\le 1$, since it need not be. And you will have to take account of the fact that nothing in the problem as stated says that $X$ is positive. The handling of the inequalities is quite tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $y\geqslant0$, let $A_y=[−y+1≤X^2≤y+1]$ then;

- If $0\leqslant y\leqslant1$, then $A_y=[-\sqrt{y+1}\leqslant X\leqslant-\sqrt{1-y}]\cup[\sqrt{1-y}\leqslant X\leqslant\sqrt{y+1}]$.
- If $y\geqslant1$, then $A_y=[-\sqrt{y+1}\leqslant X\leqslant\sqrt{y+1}]$.

This allows to deduce $F_Y$ in terms of $F_X$.